# Problem with playing sound through USB headphones

Tags: sound

I am currently using Ubuntu 15.10 and my USB headphones just stopped working for some reason. I have a Skullcandy Slayer headset(as seen on the picture). But it would play any sound through it. When i choose to play sound through the top input, it works fine(but that is through my screen) and that audio sucks. What to do.
Hope you guys can help

[image: Picture of my sound bar settings]

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around with the USB and now a second option for the headset popped up, some analog input, and that works. I still dont get why the first one dident work to begin with. But heck, if it works it works